# Why is there a large statue of Hindu god Shiva " the destroyer" located at CERN? Any philosophic reasons?

Tags: philosophy-of-religion, physics, quantum-physics, hinduism

Robert Oppenheimer famously quoted Hindu scripture when the first atomic weapon was detonated saying " now I have become death the destroyer of worlds"  Is there some worry that the work done at CERN could be destructive to the planet?      https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lb13ynu3Iac

Or is it due to some other philosophic implication of Shiva about particle physics?

Comment: This seems to be more a question of history than a question about philosophy.

Comment: He actually quoted the Bhagavad Gita verse 11.12 - "If the radiance of a thousand suns were to burst forth at once in the sky, that would be like the splendor of the Mighty One.". Your question is not one for this forum.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=lb13ynu3Iac.     Here is Oppenheimer in his own words!

Comment: That's also chapter 11. He might have said that afterwards while still there, but its recorded at the moment of explosion, it was verse 12.

Comment: There are more things in heaven and earth, Horatio (Swami Vishwanananda) than are dreamt of in your philosophy.   Shakespeare, Hamlet

Comment: The passage Oppenheimer referenced was spoken by Krishna an avatar of Vishnu the preserver in the Bhagavad Gita, not Shiva. Shiva is known as The Destroyer in the Hindu Trimurti, but has many aspects & manifestations, including as fount of the river Ganges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, I don't think the implication is in accord with [Oppenheimer](https://youtu.be/n8H7Jibx-c0).

Per: https://cds.cern.ch/record/745737?ln=en "Carl Sagan drew the metaphor between the cosmic dance of the Nataraj and the modern study of the 'cosmic dance' of subatomic particles" & "The statue is a gift from India, celebrating CERN's long association with India which started in the 1960's and continues strongly today."